# How can I trigger servlet while Tomcat starting time

Tags: java, apache, servlets, tomcat7

we develops a project name as `FirstApplication` for sending,consuming messages from `Activemq` and deployed in `Tomcat7`.After deploying,we have to trigger `http://localhost:8080/FirstApplication/PackageName/SecondConsumer` link only 1 time.So far it's fine.

My doubt,later If we restart the server,again first time we have to trigger that servlet corresponding link.Instead of doing like this,I want to configure.

Note: what I want,servlet should be evaluate automatically whenever `Tomcat server` start.servlet placed under `WebApps/FirstApplication/WEB-INF/src/classes/PackageName/SecondConsumer.java`.

For this, I tried with the following code using `servletContextListener`class.

```
 public class SecondConsumer extends HttpServlet implements ServletContextListener{
 @Override
 protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
   //my business code
 }
 @Override
 public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

 @Override
 public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }
}
```

and added `<Listener>`in my `web.xml(which is placed under WebApps/FirstApplication/WEB-INF/web.xml)` file in the following way.

```
    <listener>
    <listener-class>PackageName.SecondConsumer</listener-class>
   </listener>
```

If you observe my code, I didn't implement any code under `contextInitialized and contextDestroyed` methods.Just i want to evaluate this servlet code while `server` starting time.

I tried in the above way,it's not working.

please can anyone suggest me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do your initialization in a class which implements `ServletContextListener`, so you need something like this

```
@WebListener
public class AppServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("ServletContextListener destroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
         //do your init steps here  
    }
}
```

This piece of code will execute whenever your server starts or stops. Note that `WebListener` annotation works only in Java EE 6, prior to that you would need to define `<listener>` element in a `web.xml`.

Comment: you mean Am I need to write one more java file.Basically I am not a `Java` developer so can you explain clearly.Am I need to define `Listener` element into my `WebApps/firstApplication/WEB-INF/web.xml`.

Comment: Yes, this will be a new class (file). No, you don't need to define `<listener>` element in web.xml, `@WebListener` annotation is enough (in case you use Java EE 6  - which you probably do).

Comment: I modified my question with what I tried based on your suggestion.it's not working.can you check it once whether is it right.

Comment: You really can't extend `HttpServlet` so remove that declaration from your listener and it should work then. Your listener is simply just not a servlet, it's just a listener which allows you to execute some code upon server startup or end.

Comment: Thanks you.. I got it it's working fine without servlet

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat while running create an instance of servlet, so if you want to invoke servlet please use context listner class which actually triggers while running tomcat itself.

Thanks

Comment: Basically I am not a `Java` developer. If you know any tutorials about this suggest me or can you explain clearly with my names(What I mention in my question).

Comment: This link will help you to understand the basic of contextlistner - [link](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure, what you want. If you simply want to execute code while starting up the tomcat, you con configure a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html)